# How to detect writeable capacity of nfc chip

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nfc, proximity

I wanna know a tag's writeable capacity.

What am i doing:

- subscribing for a message

> m_proxdevice.SubscribeForMessage("WriteableTag",
> OnTagDetect);

- receive the message

> private void OnTagDetect(ProximityDevice sender,
> ProximityMessage message)
>
> ```
> {
>
>    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message.Data.Capacity.ToString());
>
> }
> ```

but every time the capacity is just 4. I'm doing something wrong, but what?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

message.Data.Capacity is the wrong property.

Use

```
int writeableSize = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(message.Data.ToArray(), 0);
```

instead.